# Появление блока по клику на ссылку

Tags: javascript, angular2

Немного знаю Javascript и Jquery. Столкнулся с Angular 6 CLI.
Задача такая. Есть страница - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь по нажатию на "Показать больше" блок "Мои достижения" должен раскрываться до 9-и иконок. Что-то типа onclick - display: block.

Но нативные функции JS в Ангуляре почему-то не работают.

```
myFunction() {
document.getElementById('aaa').setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
```

}

Вот так не работает.

Как быть? Как-то можно через Toggle, вроде.

Comment: Вам надо почитать документацию по angular. Это будет эффективнее, чем читать ответы здесь, даже если вам смогут его предоставить.

Comment: если у вас стоит angular, то забудьте про манипуляции с дом js

Comment: Они не работают, потому что DOM парсер ищет `myFunction` в `window`, а не в компоненте. Зачем вам нативные JS функции если в Angular свой механизм байндинга событий? ` <div class="show-me-more-tabs" (click)="myFunction()">Показать больше</div>`